# Task thread id changes after calling a dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, task

I am trying to update the UI after await. It was working good until I open a form before the `Task.Delay`, then I see that the thread id has changed.

Can anyone tell what's wrong here?

```
private async void TestTaskThread()
{       
    this.Text += " : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();

    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
    form2.ShowDialog();
    await Task.Delay(7);
    this.Text += " : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString();
}
```

Comment: The only thing you're doing wrong is expecting the same managed thread to pick up after `await`. Why do you expect that?

Comment: @CodeCaster preserving the context is the standard behavior of `await`, that can be configured by `ConfigureAwait`. And for Windows Forms applications the context is the UI thread.

Comment: What's missing here is how/where you're calling `TestTaskThread()`. You should always get back `1`. So, something else is going on.

Comment: This will work perfectly if `TestTaskThread` is called on the UI thread. I suspect it is *not* being called on the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate it. I added a button and on click I call the `TestTaskThread` method. The thread Id remains 1.

```
private async void btnShowDialogFromAsync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await TestTaskThread();
}
```

I also changed the return value of the method to `Task`.

The only way to replicate it is by configuring the `await` to skip restoring the context.

```
await Task.Delay(7).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: @Yoav in my configuration it doesn't. Windows 10, .NET Framework 4.7.2, C# 7.3, Visual Studio 2017 15.9.11, Start Without Debugging (Ctrl+F5)